# How to sumbit a form wizard using jQuery steps

Tags: jquery, jquery-steps

I have installed jQuery steps, and want to make a form with a step wizard.
Problem is how to sumbit the form with PHP when the "Finish" button appears.
All the code below works, exept the handling of the last submit.

**My form example code:**

```
<form method="POST" action="#" role="form">
    <div id="wizard">
        <h2>Info</h2>
        <section>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="text">Email address:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text">
              </div>
        </section>

        <h2>Second Step</h2>
        <section>
           //form stuff
        </section>

        <h2>Third Step</h2>
        <section>
           //form stuff
        </section>

        <h2>Forth Step</h2>
        <section>
            form stuff
        </section>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Script that calls jQuery steps:**

```
<script>
    $(function ()
    {
        $("#wizard").steps({
            headerTag: "h2",
            bodyTag: "section",
            transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
            stepsOrientation: "vertical"
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Last i want to sumbit the form wizard to db using PHP:**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //save values
}
```

?>

Comment: found a solution to this ?

Answer (score 2):

The `onFinished` method can be used for submitting the form to the server

```
onFinished: function (event, currentIndex) {
    var form = $(this);
    // Submit form input
    form.submit();
},
```